# Split string on semi-colon, then loop through results

Tags: sql-server-2005, split, cursor

Basically I want to be able to take this row value

```
hello;my;apple;world;is;good
```

And then get a select back in rows.

But obviously this query comes from select mycolumn from mytable;

- hello
- my
- apple
- world
- is
- good

Then throw it into a cursor loop

Is there a way to do this with a select;

```
DECLARE
 TCursor CURSOR FOR
  //select split here?
OPEN TCursor  ;
FETCH NEXT FROM TCursor ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  FETCH NEXT FROM TCursor ;
END;

CLOSE TCursor  ;
DEALLOCATE TCursor ;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a split function, e.g. (updated to deal with a trailing `;`, a scenario not outlined in the question):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item FROM
      ( 
        SELECT Item = RTRIM(y.i.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'))
        FROM 
        ( 
          SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
            + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
            + '</i>').query('.')
        ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
      ) AS x WHERE LEN(Item) > 0
   );
GO
```

Then you can say any of these:

```
--DECLARE TCursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 

  SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML('hello;my;apple;world;is;good', ';');
  SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML('hello;my;apple;world;is;good;', ';');
  SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML('apple;', ';');
```

My guess is that you don't really need a cursor here, but it's tough to offer guidance without knowing what you're doing inside the loop.

As an aside, while this XML function works fine as a standalone answer, there are [better, more scalable solutions that take a little more effort](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Comment: Aaron - what happens if there is only one value there like apple;

Comment: @Mike - did you try it? You'll get the same thing if your string has an additional trailing `;` like `foo;bar;good;` - one extra row containing a blank string. You can filter that out in the function (e.g. `WHERE LEN(RTRIM(y.i.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'))) > 0` or add a subquery and check `Item`) or you can skip this last row by checking the length in the cursor.